# is "on it" must be there in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I have seen the following sentence in a book:

..., but the branch with the eight apples **on it** was in his hand when I first saw him.

My question is, is "on it" a necessary part from this sentence? Can I just say: "the branch with eight apples was in his hand when I first saw him" ? 
If I can, please explain the different meaning (if there is a difference) between the sentences with "on it" and the one without "on it".

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Technically it's redundant.  There is no difference in meaning as the average reader would read it.

Comment: So far the sense is exactly the same, you may use either versions with or without "on it" ; it's juste a matter of style.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "on it" specifies the relation of the applies to the branch. The apples are on the branch.

Without "on it" the relation is unspecified. The apples might be simply near the branch. Even if it is likely that the apples are on the branch (and without "on it" you would probably still guess that), you would use "on it" to be sure there was no confusion.